# Change Date format to MM-DD-YYY

Tags: node.js, reactjs, mongodb, express, mongoose

I've been searching for a fix on this, seems like it should be something fairly simple.

I have a page showing data from a MongoDB.  Collection name is tickets and the field is ticketDate.

```
import { Link, useParams } from "react-router-dom";
import { Col, Row, Container } from "../Grid";
import Jumbotron from "../Jumbotron";
import API from "../../utils/API";

function TicketDetails(props) {
  const [tickets, setTickets] = useState({})

  // When this component mounts, grab the ticket with the _id of props.match.params.id
  // e.g. localhost:3000/Tickets/599dcb67f0f16317844583fc
  const {id} = useParams()
  useEffect(() => {
    API.getTicket(id)
      .then(res => setTickets(res.data))
      .catch(err => console.log(err));
  }, [id])

  return (
    <Container fluid>
      <Row>
        <Col size="md-12">
          <Jumbotron>
            <h1>
            <strong>
              Ticket # - {tickets.ticketNum}                      
            </strong>
            </h1>
          </Jumbotron>
        </Col>
      </Row>
      <Row>
        <Col size="md-10 md-offset-1">
          <article>
            <h1>Ticket Details</h1>
            <p>
              <strong>
               {tickets.ticketNum} 
                <br></br>
               {tickets.ticketDate}         
                <br></br>
                {tickets._id}
               </strong>  
            </p>
          </article>
        </Col>
      </Row>
      <Row>
        <Col size="md-2">
          <Link to="/Tickets">← Back to Tickets</Link>
        </Col>
      </Row>
    </Container>
  );
}
export default TicketDetails
```

The way it is here, it shows that date in the following format: 2020-07-04T05:00:00.000Z

I'd like it to just show up like 7-4-2020 or something similar.  Can someone point me in the right direction?

Thanks,

-N8

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: I've tried using momentJS and date-fns as well as some other ideas that I've came across in Google.  Unfortunately, I'm still very new at this, and I'm sure if those would work, I wasn't using them correctly or in the correct place.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do that by using the npm package `moment.js` https://momentjs.com/

Here you can find examples of usage : http://zetcode.com/javascript/momentjs/

In your case it should be like this :
`moment("2020-07-04T05:00:00.000Z").format("MM-DD-YYYY")`

Comment: Thank you Garsivirus, that was a big help.  I appreciate it.